# How to create nested properties

Tags: c#, properties

How are nested properties like `dataTable.Columns[0].ColumnName` created?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "nested property" What you have is a property of type `List<Column>` (or `Column[]` or whatever). The elements in that collection have properties of their own.

Answer (score 6):

They're not 'created' per se, it's just `Columns` is collection of objects that are of some type, and that type exposes the property `ColumnName`.

```
class Some
{
    string Property { get; set; }
}
class Foo
{
    public List<Some> Objects { get; set; }
}

foo.Objects[0].Property
```

Answer (score 1):

Property returns an object which has own properties and so on

Answer (score 1):

In your example, dataTable.Columns is a simple indexed property, that returns another object which has a property called ColumnName.

For Example:

```
class Table
{
    private Column[] columns;
    public Column Columns[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return columns[index];
        }
    }
}

class Column
{
    public string ColumnName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

(Not 100% sure about syntax, I have not used C# in a while)

Answer (score 1):

`dataTable.Columns[0].ColumnName` combines the concept of a `property` and the concept of an `indexer`:

- The object `dataTable` exposes a property named `Columns`
- `Columns` is of a collection type, so an `indexer` is used, to address a certain element in that collection, `Columns[0]` for the first one (The first one plus zero), `Columns[1]` for the second one (The first one pluse one), a.s.o.
- Each of these elements again is an object, exposing the property `ColumnName`

So `dataTable.Columns[0].ColumnName` should be read as, "From the object dataTable's collection-property Columns take the first element's property ColumnName"